# Recreating photos library from external photo library after clean install

Tags: time-machine, photos, photos.app

I've had no end of corruption problems with my photo library ever since the transfer from iPhoto to photos.

I've completely recreated a new machine and **I am trying to re-create a fresh photos library by importing the photos from my old library** (I've got a direct backup and a Time Machine).

I'm assuming that if I just import the original photos then I will lose meta information such as favourites, projects, books, calendars etc.

**Is there a 'clean way' to import (most of) the photos with their meta information?**

I don't want to simply copy-paste the library from the external drive to the new computer.

I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if what you ask is possible, but did you try [repairing your Photos library](http://osxdaily.com/2015/05/21/repair-photos-library-photos-app-mac-os-x/)?